# Tagline Formatting in Latex

Tags: cv

I am pretty new to Latex, I am using a template which has a profile picture in the tagline which i do not want to use. But once I remove the image, my tagline text goes over the header
[image: Text going over tagline]
Here is my tagline code:

```
\documentclass[%singlesided,
               doublesided,
               paper=a4,
               fontsize=10pt
              ]{my-resume}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% set geometry
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength\highlightwidth{8cm}
\setlength\headerheight{4cm}            % note that margintop gets added to this value, i.e. the header bar is 5cm
\setlength\marginleft{1cm}
\setlength\marginright{\marginleft}      % needs to be 1.5 times to be actually equal. why?
\setlength\margintop{1cm}
\setlength\marginbottom{1cm}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FONTS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Carlito}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% COLORS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\colorlet{highlightbarcolor}{lightgray}
\colorlet{headerbarcolor}{darkgray}

\colorlet{headerfontcolor}{white}
\colorlet{accent}{awesome-red}
\colorlet{heading}{black}
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% set document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\name{Mr. Mohammed Ismail}
\tagline{I am passionate about programming and how the world is advanced by
the fourth industrial revolution day by day. I am very team and work
orientated and love helping my fellow class mates to learn about why
programming in this century is very important. The Use of Technology
has really impacted the world and teaches small business owners how
to be competitive with bigger more reputable companies.}


\makeheader
```

Comment: Please post the `MWE` in executable format, hope `my-resume.cls` was the customized one...

Answer (score 0):

add a \\ at the end like so

\tagline{I am passionate about programming and how the world advances thanks to
the fourth industrial revolution day by day. I am very team and work
oriented and I love helping my classmates learn about why
Programming in this century is very important. The use of technology
has truly impacted the world and teaches small business owners how
be competitive with larger and more reputable companies. \\ }